# Send data back to Previous Activity from Current Activity which is opened by Other Activity

Tags: android

I have 6 activities - A, B, C, D, E, F.

A opens B, B opens C and so on till F. I am currently at F and then from F, I opened B using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and maintained A in backstack.

 Now I want to send data back to A from B activity when back button is pressed. Please Help!!

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1055241

Comment: @gprathour The answer provided in the link would be helpful if I was going from A->B and then needs data back to A on back press but here I am starting B activity from F and then needs data back to A. Plz read question one more time..

Comment: @SahilMunjal the link provided by gprathour is for you to get basic idea how startActivityForResult works you have to modify that according to your requirement.

Comment: @Pavan Bro, I am already using startActivityForResult when I open activity from A->B and then I am able to send data back to A successfully.

Answer (score 0):

there will be two approach one if you use startActivityForResult then need to be used in all 6 activity this will require code change in all activity for onActivityResult this means you have to maintain all 6 activity in stack till your work complted when you complete with F just setresult with data and finish F which will received by E just pass received data with result to D and finish E you have to maintain this till A, this will lead to you extra coding and effort.

Second approach is don't maintain A in stack as you stated opened B using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and maintained A in backstack. just like this open A with data you have in B, but i don't know this is feasible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static Method to send data from one activity to another activity **(when activities don't have direct link and also don't want to recreate first activity)**.

In First activty..

```
public class A extends Activity {

static A INSTANCE;
String data=""; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

INSTANCE=this; 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public static A getActivityInstance()
{
  return INSTANCE;
}

 public void getData(String b_data)
 {
  data = b_data;
  }
 }
```

Second Activity:

```
 public class Second extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main1);     
 }
}
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
{
  A.getActivityInstance().getData("Your data");  
  super.onBackPressed(); 
 }
```

Hope this will help you.